# Passing html into Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs2

At the moment I pass some parameters into a vue component

```
 <Slider
      :images= "['/img/work/slide2.png', '/img/work/slide2.png', '/img/work/slide3.png']"
      :html="['<div>hello</div>', '<div>goodbye</div>']"
    </Slider>
```

The slider is either an 'html' slider or one with images.

This works fine although the html I pass in is going to get a lot more complex, maybe 30 lines and this will be harder to read and manage as params.

Can I pass in an external reference and pull that into the component?

```
<div v-for="content in html">
    <div class="work-slide">{{ content }}</div>
</div>
```

As you can see the loop in the component is a very simple v-for.

Answer (score 37):

Don't pass HTML using attributes but using [Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html):

> Suppose we have a component called my-component with the following template:

> ```
> <div>
>   <h2>I'm the child title</h2>
>   <slot>
>     This will only be displayed if there is no content
>     to be distributed.
>   </slot>
> </div>
> ```

> And a parent that uses the component:

> ```
> <div>
>   <h1>I'm the parent title</h1>
>   <my-component>
>     <p>This is some original content</p>
>     <p>This is some more original content</p>
>   </my-component>
> </div>
> ```

> The rendered result will be:

> ```
> <div>
>   <h1>I'm the parent title</h1>
>   <div>
>     <h2>I'm the child title</h2>
>     <p>This is some original content</p>
>     <p>This is some more original content</p>
>   </div>
> ```

```
</div>
```

You can also use [Named Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots) if you want to pass more than one field containing HTML.

Answer (score 6):

You can inject raw html into Vue components with the [v-html directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML).

Comment: While this would work, you do not get any data-bindings this way.

Comment: You can certainly bind data with v-html, e.g. <p v-html="mydataVariable"></p>

Comment: How do I pass the html to mydataVariable from the html which uses the component?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem in a project some months ago. I fixed it passing the HTML code in base64 format.

my parent component :

```
<wysywyg id="ssaasa" :bal="to64('<strong>Me</strong>')"></wysywyg>
```

my method:

```
methods: {
        to64(html) {
            return btoa(html)
        }
    }
```

my component:

```
<template>
    <div class="RenderHTMLEditor mx-3">
        <label class="subtitle-1 pb-3">{{label}}</label>
        <textarea html="true" v-model="to64"
        width="100%"
        :style="'height:'+height+'px;'"
        wysywyg="true"
        :name="id" :id="id"
        class="tinywy">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['label', 'id', 'height', 'bal'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            
        }
    },
    computed: {
        to64: function() {
            return atob(this.bal)
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        window.initWy(this.id)
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.RenderHTMLEditor {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Congratulations. You've just exposed your site to the wonderful world of XSS attacks! :) - Although a novel solution to this problem, please don't do this, especially with v-model. Slots exist for this very use-case, and will protect you (at least partially) from exposing yourself to attacks. You're one malicious [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) away from disaster.