# Cannot Render $children in Another Component

Tags: vue.js

I would like to have a dynamic content so I tried something like below. When I log `$children[0]`, I get a proper data but nothing is shown on the HTML. Is there way to render `$children`?

Main:

```
<template>
   <foo>
      <h1>Content should be rendered {{number}} time.</h1>
   </foo>
</template>
<script>
components: { Foo },
data() {
  return {
    number: 1
  }
}
...
</script>
```

Foo:

```
<template>
   <div v-html="$children[0]"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing html into Vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923775/passing-html-into-vue-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html). Simply replace `<div v-html="$children[0]"></div>` with `<slot></slot>`.