# Variable form inside dialog with Vue and Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've made a dialog with a certain structure that a I want to re-utilize with a form inside of it. This form it's completely variable (it could contain v-text-fields, v-textarea, v-selects, etc...). 
How can I accomplish that knowing that the dialog is a child element and depends of the parent to know how the form will be?. It's possible to bind an entire component?

```
<template>
 <!-- someData -->

 <ChildDialog :variableForm="formComponent"/> // Something like that?

 <!-- moreData -->
</template>
```

Thank you, hope you understand my question.

Comment: Have you considered using slots? like used here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923775/passing-html-into-vue-component

Comment: Thank you!!, that's what I need. I will post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Abdulaziz Yesuf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10970649/abdulaziz-yesuf) said, with **slots** you can accomplish my problem ([Passing html into Vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923775/passing-html-into-vue-component))